# Is there a way to compute a exponentiation of $(X-1)$, without inversion?

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, exponentiation

If we're in any finite field and we want to compute something like $x^{p^k-1}$ we can use cyclotomic polynomials to factorize. But we allways will have to compute $x^{p-1}=x^p x^{-1}$.

Therefore, we have to invert. But is there any trick, that I could be in the position to compute that value, without inverting so? I'm thinking about homomorphisms/isomorphisms, to switch that problem to something like $x^{f(p-1)}$.

In all those steps, p is a prime. I would recommend, if there is no "do it, I know how." just do a brainstorming with suggestions.

---

## Special Case

In my special case I consider any $A\in\mathbb F_{p^{16}}$ and trying to compute $A^{p^8-1}\in\mathbb F_{p^{16}}$. I would like to find a way without splitting up like this: $A^{p^8}A^{-1}$, where $p\equiv 5\bmod 8$. The way I'm looking for does not require to compute any inverse.

---

## Possible way with inversion

I know that there are different kinds of "Square-and-Multiply" algorithm, like Montgomery, Sliding Window, ... Since the $A$ is random, I cannot precompute (or I do not see any sence in doing this, because the random entropy for $\mathbb F_{p^{16}}$ is just huge ..)

The only terms, I could precompute (which would be senseful) are the powers of $x$.

If I consider the representation $$A=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^k$$ with $a_k\in\mathbb F_p$ and the tower $\mathbb F_{p^{16}} = \mathbb F_p[x]/(x^{16}-1)$ (is this really an equal sign, and no isomorphism sign?) I could transform that polynomial into a companion matrix, invert that matrix, and map the result back. The last part "mapt the result back" could probably be a difficult part.

Comment: Is [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) an option worth considering in your case?

Comment: Ok, the prime field is $\mathbb F_{p^{16}}$ and could be reduced to $\mathbb F_p[x]/(x^{16}-1)$.  I've got the $p^8$-Frobenius working well. So SaM would be really slow, if I could not use any trick. To think about a size, but it doesn't really matter, $p\sim 2^{340}$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers its $\mathbb F_{p^k}$

Comment: @MorganRodgers I'm trying to understand the exponentiations and, therefore, trying to implement a way, that do not require any inversion. But only, if there is a way to do this.

Comment: @MorganRodgers you're right. But, the last written $k$  is not the first written $k$. I wasn't precise enough. Let me rephrase the original question.

Comment: It seems, that there is a way to invert through cyclotomic fields without knowing the inverse. The "Guide to Pairing-Based Cryptography" (Mrabet etal. 2017) points out in Chapter 7, that if $g=f^{p^8-1}$ we get $$g^{p^8}=g^{-1}$$. Using any quadritc extension, say $\mathbb F_{p^{16}}=\mathbb F_{p^8}(\alpha)$ we get: $$g^{-1}= g_0 + \alpha g_1  $$ where $g_0,g_1\in\mathbb F_{p^8}$.But I do not get, how this will help computing $f^{p^8-1}$. @MorganRodgers

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen see pls the previous comment.
I have to state an equation right: Say point out, that this exponentiation is a simple conjugation, so $$g^{-1} = g_0 - \alpha g_1$$.